# Retain time zone information from postgresql timestamp in go

Tags: postgresql, datetime, go

I have a postgresql db with the columns date and repeat_until as timestamp with time zone. The example dates have a time zone specific format. The latter is winter time.

`2017-08-28 09:00:00+02`, `2017-12-31 23:00:00+01`

Using string and time.Time the first gives the time relative to GMT+0, the latter seconds (not unix timestamp).

```
import (
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type Event struct {
    Date            string
    RepeatUntil     time.Time   `db:"repeat_until"`
}


event := Event{}
rows, _ := db.Queryx("select * from events order by date")
for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.StructScan(&event)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v", event)
}
```

`Date:"2017-08-28T07:00:00Z"`

`RepeatUntil:time.Time{sec:63650354400, nsec:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}`

What is the recommended way to retain time zone information? time.Time seems obvious but I am not sure how it got to seconds which is in year 3986 in unixtime.

I'm using [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx).

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. It DOES retain the timezone. https://play.golang.org/p/Lj_uxCts1R . Oh wait... I see, your qualm is with how `sqlx` is parsing it.

Comment: Have you tried using `string` in your struct instead of `time.Time` and then parsing it yourself with the layout as in my playground link?

Comment: I'm actually starting to wonder if you might have an old version of the `pq` driver and need an update. According to the code I've looked through and the test cases I've seen (https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/e42267488fe361b9dc034be7a6bffef5b195bceb/encode_test.go#L191), it should have NO problem handling TimeZones properly. I suggest you run `go get -u github.com/lib/pq`

Comment: What exactly do yo mean with `retain time zone information`? `Date:"2017-08-28T07:00:00Z"` is equal to `2017-08-28 09:00:00+02` and `sec:63650354400` is number of seconds since *zero time* (January 1, year 1, 00:00:00.000000000 UTC) which is equal to `2017-12-31 23:00:00+01`

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Thank you for your input. The pq-driver was installed a few days ago so updating did not change the parsing. Date is parsed as string, RepeatUntil as time.Time. If you are being sarcastic by using the word 'qualm' I'd appreciate you refrain from that and rather not answer.

Comment: @putu If the date could be passed with timezone unchanged when the db is configured to a certain timezone. I was not aware seconds was relative to year 1. Could not find the info at https://golang.org/pkg/time/. Thank you.

Comment: @kometen Hah, seems I've been misusing the word "qualm" all my life. I meant it meaning "quarrel", or "issue/problem".

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Pardon. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The timezone in PostgreSQL is session parameter, i.e. it can be specified for each session (connection). If you don't specify it, the timezone will be inferred from setting parameters in `pg_hba.conf`. When you select records, the date/time data then will be converted automatically from database timezone to session (connection) timezone.

In your case, to get the time in specific timezone, specify it explicitly in the *connection parameters*, e.g.

```
psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
    "dbname=%s sslmode=disable TimeZone=Europe/Paris",
    host, port, user, dbname)
db, err := sqlx.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
```

The `TimeZone` can be obtained by

```
select * from pg_timezone_names;
```

Answer (score 1):

The timezone can be configured during a single connection or by [altering](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/ii01ob%24dad%241%40reversiblemaps.ath.cx) the timezone setting in the database.

`alter database foo set timezone to 'Europe/Oslo';`

This will return the date formatted for that timezone.